# Integrating $\int_a^b dx e^{-c\sinh ^2 x}$ by parts

Tags: integration-by-parts

I'm having trouble finding a reasonable way to integrate the following by parts:

$$\int_a^b dx \ e^{-c\sinh ^2 x}$$

The idea is to get an expansion in powers of $c$ (I have to later show that this expansion doesn't work in fact), but I have no clue how to do an integration by parts with this integrand. I tried adding a $\frac{d}{dx}(x)$ but this leads to a huge mess. I don't know what else to do, that is how to write

$$e^{-c\sinh ^2 x} = f(x)g'(x)$$

such that there is some sort of recurring structure to the successive integrations.

The constants $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary, $c$ is very large.

edit: I'm not looking for an antiderivative, but for an expansion in $c$

Comment: i think there is no elementary antiderivative

Comment: I'm not looking for an antiderivative, but for an expansion in $c$

Comment: Are you sure that the idea isn't to expand $e^{\text{stuff}}$ as a power series and then integrate termwise?

Comment: That would make more sense but the problem states 'integrate by parts' and gives reference to a previous problem where that's what one did... which is why this is confusing me